# Loading Rails activerecord associations from memcache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, memcached, associations

Ive 2 models in my app - a Request and a Category
A Request belongs to a Category. The system contains many requests but only a few categories. The categories are static and never change and they hold other associations which are also static. I can use memcache to store the category and related associations.

How do I tell rails when it loads a particular Request to load the associated Category from memcache and not the DB ?

```
req = Request.find(id)
req.category (Curr this hits the DB - want it to hit memcache)
```

Is overriding the method req.category the only way ?

Comment: so what have you done on this subject?

Answer (score 0):

Memcache is a key/value store and can only store strings, therefore you'd have to write a custom method to retrieve the category as well as serialize your object somehow.

Take a look here : [What is the best way to store an ActiveRecord object in memcached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393974/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-an-activerecord-object-in-memcached)

Comment: Thanks for the link. But it seems that I did not require to do anything special for caching an AR object in memcache - it works out of the box. I on Rails 3.2.2

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think your solution is not as good as you think.

So you have like 20 Categories and lets say 2000 Requests you want to fetch. If doing it with ActiveRecord you can do this in two queries

```
Request.includes(:category)
```

This will hit only two times the DB, and with proper indexing it should be pretty fast. I have just tested the numbers above with sqLite and I got it in 13.4ms what it's pretty acceptable. With index on the foreign key, I'm not sure why but it got down to 11.3ms.

If you implement your "solution" with memcached, I'm just supposing, but it actually can get worse, since you will hit the cache as many times as Request you fetch, so in this example you would hit the memcached 2000 times, even if they take 1ms each it would be 2000ms=2s.

Comment: What you say is correct when Im retrieving multiple Requests. However my scenario is when loading a single request. In such a case includes will not improve the situation as there will be 2 queries and what Im looking for is one query for the request and category retrieved from memcache. Also as mentioned in the question the category object contains other nested objects (i.e its a heavy static object)